# PhantomJS/CasperJS IDE Helper

Tags: ide, phantomjs, phpstorm, casperjs

Is there any way to get IDE support for CasperJS functions? I am currently using PhpStorm, but also tried in netbeans, it won't know which functions are defined. It is quite irritating that I get `Unresolved variable / undefined function` IDE warnings for all the functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried to copy `\casperjs\modules\*.js` files to the project, most of the functions got "defined".

PhpStorm: Download the casperjs.zip from casperjs.org, it will contain a `modules` folder, copy every .js file to your project. (I put them in an IDE_HELPER folder)

An IDE helper javascript file would still be much better, but it is working.

Alternatively: You can also attach these files as external libraries, so it won't bother you while browsing your own files.

It should work in other IDEs too.

Answer (score 4):

Disclaimer: I'm talking about JetBrains products.

I encountered this problem myself. The easiest way to solve it is to click on a bottom right icon [image: Hector] (Finally, I understand that is this for!).

It will show you which libraries are associated with an open file. The only thing you have to do is to click on «**Libraries in scope**» and add your library by clicking «**Download**»

Comment: Yes! That's the one

Answer (score 1):

I know it's an old post, but after not finding any IDE Helper too I managed to write a script that creates one by scraping the content off of the official docs. You can find out more about the IDE Helper on my website:

http://christophersax.com/2016/casperjs-ide-helper/

(It's free of course)

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can add casperjs as a Resource in your Preferences.

Go to `Project` > `Directories` > `+ Add Content Root` > Add casperjs folder then > `Mark as Resource Root`.